# Re-enable Secure Boot after Installing Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-card, uefi, secure-boot

After having trouble with no image after installing a graphics card, I disabled Secure Boot (Still UEFI, not Legacy). Everything is now working, and I would like to re-enable Secure Boot. Is there a way to do this? The machine is a Dell XPS 8930, OEM everything else.

Comment: Have you tried to simply enable it, exactly how you, disabled it by modifying the firmware settings?

Comment: @Ramhound I disabled it through the BIOS. If I reenable it now, I am not able to boot until I remove the graphics card and return to the factory-present integrated graphics.

Comment: Please indicate if Windows is installed on a GPT or MBR partition?  A GPU being installed should not determine if Secure Boot can be enabled or disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound It's GPT